Supply motor with higher voltage than ESC gives
There are many motors that take in high voltages. But most ESCs have BEC outputs of just 5V or sometimes up to 8V. Although, many motors need 20V+ voltages, many ESCs supply just low voltages. What is then done to get a motor its required voltage, if it needs an ESC to work?

Buy the ESC that matches the motor?

This is the problem. All ESCs have descriptions of something like this "BEC output: 5.7V/3A switch mode built-in" or a maximum of 8V. So there are none, that ouput higher than 20V electricty to the motor. Or does this not mean that?

The motor is not fed from the Battery Elimination Circuit's output, but from the ESC.
It is pure happenstance that BEC is offered as part of an ESC more often than as a separate/independent component - such would go as a buck converter or step-down converter. (Shared components are just input connector&capacitor.)
The whole BEC idea is to use the propulsion battery to power receiver&servos, eliminating a separate battery there. The motor battery will have the voltage, power&energy deemed suitable for the motor.
The ESC needs to be specified for that voltage&amperage, too.
There is a Drones and Model Aircraft stack exchange.

.So you mean that, the power supply for the motor is seperate from the ESC and the power supply for the ESC is just used  as a power supply for the ESC, so it has electricity to send impulses to the motor?

The one battery supplies power to both the ESC and the BEC, BEC built in to the ESC or not. I can confirm the power supply for the ESC is used as a power supply for the ESC.

No. I meant to ask, if there are 2 sepereate batteries. One that powers the ESC and one that powers the motor?

An ESC goes between battery and motor. The whole point of BEC is making do with one single battery.

Then, why are there no ESCs, that have a battery output of higher than 5V. What do people do to overcome this problem and give the motor a higher voltage, if the motor needs an ESC?

Or does "BEC output: 5.7V/3A switch mode built-in" in the ESCs description, not mean that the ESC outputs a voltage of maximum 5.7V?

The motor gets connected to the motor output(s, in case of a brushless motor, which needs electronic commutation). It does not connect to the BEC DC output, typically in the range of 5 V to 6 V. The BEC output voltage has no relation to the propulsion motor(s) voltage. If you hyperlinked a description of the offer you are referring to, somebody might find a connection diagram or similar nearby.

Ah. Thank you. So, for example, would this ESC have a voltage of crica 11V becasue in its description it mentions "Battery: 2-3 cells Lipo (5-9 cells NI-xx)".

(HobbyKing keeps a User Manual Brushless speed controller XERUN 60 A/120 A including a wiring diagram with a cooling fan: don't significantly load the ESC without guaranteed air flow.) Assume the battery voltage gets passed to the motor with as little drop as they could muster. (Things are more complicated.) The ESC is specified for 5 NiMH cells (say, 6 V nominal) to 3 lithium cells (11.1 V). (One place reads 4-9 NiMH cells; 4 may be an error.) Battery voltage cut-off may be as low as 5.2 V; seeing the design is pre-2010, I wouldn't bet it passes more then almost $V_{bat}$ at BEC output.

So isn't it possible for the motor to just get the signals and everything from the ESC, but have the power to be taken directly from the power supply. Like for example it could be possible for this motor (as it has a seperate connection for the power supply). Right?

Not right. You still got it all backwards. You need a decent introduction to 3-phase machines, and how to drive them from DC. The StackExchange Question&answer format is no good here. Please search/ask over at Drones and Model Aircraft for such material. (The power supply connection with the motor hyperlinked is not for propulsion. It supplies the Hall sensors (for tight motor control).)

ok.............
